# move_uploaded_file does not work if temp file is not created by PHP

Tags: php, yii2

`move_uploaded_file()` does not work if I create a file using
`tempnam`.

I am using Yii2's `UploadedFile::getInstance()` method to create a file instance.  Now, the difference here is the fact that I am populating  `$_FILES` like the following, before making the instance:

```
function addToFiles($key, $model, $url) {   
    $tempName = tempnam(ini_get('upload_tmp_dir'), 'php_files');
    $originalName = basename(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
    $curl = new \common\components\Curl();
    $imgRawData = $curl->get($url);
    $fp = fopen($tempName, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $imgRawData);
    fclose($fp);

    $_FILES[$model] = array(
        'name' => [$key => $originalName],
        'type' => [$key => 'image/jpeg'],
        'tmp_name' => [$key => $tempName],
        'error' => [$key => 0],
        'size' => [$key => strlen($imgRawData)],
    );
}
```

Then, I create an instance like following:

```
 $file = UploadedFile::getInstance($instance, $attr);
```

Dump of the `$file`:

```
yii\web\UploadedFile#1
(
    [name] => '20421_33_t.jpg'
    [tempName] => 'D:\\xampp\\tmp\\php8005.tmp'
    [type] => 'image/jpeg'
    [size] => 2527
    [error] => 0
)
```

Now, if I call:

```
$file->saveAs($folder . '/' . $filename);
```

It just returns `false`, without any warning or exception.

Now, I did some digging around and found out that Yii uses `move_uploaded_file()` (without any error suppression operator) in `saveAs()` method. The following is the core `saveAs()` method.

```
public function saveAs($file, $deleteTempFile = true)
{
    if ($this->error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        if ($deleteTempFile) {
            return move_uploaded_file($this->tempName, $file);
        } elseif (is_uploaded_file($this->tempName)) {
            return copy($this->tempName, $file);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

As per `move_uploaded_file()` [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php#refsect1-function.move-uploaded-file-returnvalues) a warning should have been issued when return is false, but I get nothing! Error reporting + Yii2's debugger is enabled in my setup and it should break out on slightest of the error!

Question is- Is this by design? Or is this a bug? Or perhaps I am doing something horribly wrong?

By the way, I am not really looking for an alternative solution because I have it  already. I am curious to find out why this does not work, more than anything.

**Things to note:**

- `$folder` is writable. `is_dir($folder) && is_writable($folder)` returns true.
- `$file->tempName` exists and not readonly! `readfile($file->tempName)` reads the file without a problem.
- I even tried `chmod($file->tempName , 0777);` but it doesn't work.
- The same method works perfectly if I do not use `addToFiles` method, and upload the same image file from the form. In such cases, the dump of the instance is exactly the same ( only the tempName  is different obviously, e.g. `D:\\xampp\\tmp\\phpDBCC.tmp`), but the file uploads.

Comment: First line of the documentation `...valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST upload mechanism)...`

Comment: Perhaps the word "uploaded" means something different to you, but in PHP, it means "uploaded" not "created using tempnam"

Comment: @JonStirling  anyway to trick this? Thanks for clearing it out anyway :)

Comment: Most of your question appears to be about why `move_uploaded_file()` does not move files that have not been uploaded but then you make it rather clear that you're aware of the reason. Then, your question is just about the lack of warning or I'm missing something?

Comment: "I am not really looking for an alternative solution" <--- and yet that's really what you truly need.

Comment: @jszobody I am not looking for another solution, but I am open to ideas that involves using tempnam :)

Comment: @SugatoSengupta Nope. You're problem revolves around trying to fake an upload with `tempnam`. You need to abandon that approach entirely.

Comment: Okay understood :)

Comment: Pretty much everything you've written could be replaced by two-ish lines of code. `$imgRawData = file_get_contents($url); file_put_contents($folder . '/' . $filename, $imgRawData);`. You could even combine those into a single line of code. ;-)

Comment: @jszobody in my case it could not be done directly. I have event after save which does it. I was trying to reuse that event in a child class. I will take the alternative path and override the method.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I guess I could be clearer, but English is not my first language.. So , I might not have explained the questions correctly. I had two questions.. First one was, "Why does move_uploaded_files() not work if I do it like this?".. Second one was.. Why isn't there an warning if it does not work? It might be obvious to experienced people like you but there are users who are not so experienced and need explanation on things that you take for granted.. Hope you understand my point now :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected and you need to find some other way.

Issue one: You should not modify `$_*` super globals. There are different things which can break. The is code which expects them to be immutable. If you're lucky you can get through this, but don't change it, but find a way to abstract from those files and mock the abstraction.

Issue two: `move_uploaded_files()` is a special purpose function. The purpose is to bypass security measurements (like open_basedir or, historic, safe_mode) to access specific files owned by PHP's internals. This is needed as the uploaded file is received from the client before PHP can handle the request and properly identify the script to run. This function is not supposed to be used with other files except those created by PHP on the start of the specific request.

To provide a proper solution you have to elaborate what you actually want to achieve. My guess is that you want to get data from somewhere else and don't want to have a broken file. or that purpose do something like this:

```
$tempName = tempnam($folder, 'php_files');
/* .... */
$fp = fopen($tempName, 'w');
/* ... */
fclose($fp);
rename($tempName, $folder . '/' . $filename);
```

Mind that I directly write to `$folder`. This ensures that we're using the same device thus we while storing the file we see that we have the needed rights and enough disk space. The `rename()` then is very fast as we're on the same device.

This still isn't perfect, as the script might crash in between for any reason. This would leave the temporary file there. So you'd need a cleanup routine.

Comment: Actually I wanted to reuse a method from parent class in a child class. Parent class has image upload, but child class will need to fetch image from external resource. Wanted to keep the same method for both the classes. I will be overriding the method after seeing this. Accepted :)

Answer (score 2):

PHP has [rename()](http://php.net/rename), a function that can (as its name suggests) move files. Yes, I was being ironic, the name sucks.

It's not that PHP, as any other organically evolved creature, doesn't have duplicate features, but the whole purpose of having [move_uploaded_files()](http://php.net/move_uploaded_files) is being able to *not* move certain files; more specifically, those that happened to be in the requested path but were never uploaded by the user, e.g.:

```
move_uploaded_files('/etc/passwd', '/var/www/html/img'); // false!
```

I honestly don't have the faintest idea of the attack vector this function tries to fight but I'm not a security expert and the function functionality is clear.

As about the lack of warnings, it's just as documented. Let's read carefully (emphasis is mine):

> ### Return Values
>
> Returns `TRUE` on success.
>
> If filename is not a valid upload file, then no action will occur, and
>   move_uploaded_file() will return `FALSE`.
>
> If filename i**s a valid upload** file, but **cannot be moved for some
>   reason**, no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return
>   `FALSE`. Additionally, a **warning will be issued**.

The rationale? Perhaps they thought that using `move_uploaded_file()` to move a file that was not uploaded in the fist place did not need further explanation but a system error like disk full or permission denied could use some details.

---

*I can think of perfectly valid scenarios where you may want to fake an upload (unit testing comes to my mind) but that should be based in an entirely redesigned architecture with stubs, mocks and all that fancy stuff, where move_uploaded_files() is possibly the least of your worries.*

Comment: Good explanation. Thank you! +1 :)